# PfSense IPSec VPN client

Tags: ipsec, pfsense

I am new in PfSense
I have configured site to site VPN and it works fine, "Site A" ( PfSense) and "Site B" ( SonicWall) both can access each other LAN network.
Now i have also configured IPSec Mobile client in "Site A" and it also works fine with Shrew Soft VPN client.
Now the problem is , while connect to "Site A" through Shrew Soft VPN client i can only access "Site A" LAN subnet but can not access the "Site B" LAN network though site to site VPN has been enabled and added the required network of "Site B" in 2nd Phase of IPSec Mobile configuration .

I look forward to get a workable solution.

Kind Regards 
Sk. Mustaque Mohammod .

Comment: You might be facing a whole range of problems here, including routing problems, IPSEC SA definitions and firewalling issues. Please try revising your question providing the routing tables of your client and the pfSense router, the IPSEC SAD/SPD/logs and excerpts from the firewall logs on the pfSense side.

Comment: now i have configured openvpn in pfsense and can access pfsensse network ( LAN 192.168.22.0/24) through openvpn client (LAN 15.1.1.0/24) , there is also a IPSec site to site vpn between pfsense ( LAN 192.168.22.0/24) and sonicwall ( LAN 10.1.0.0/16), site to site works, opnvpn client access works. Now i use push "route 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0" still cant access 10.1.0.0/16 from openvpn client ( LAN 15.1.1.0/24)